# nodejs handle and show mysql error messages

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to manage and show to the web user(the admins, not normal users) the errors string I get. For example, when the conecction fails I get this

> { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306]
>     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>     syscall: 'connect',
>     address: '127.0.0.1',
>     port: 3306,
>     fatal: true }

well, I can get code, errno and the other ones, but I can not get the exact message error (In this case"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED...". Is there any way to get it os this is just information to node.js?(Im working with node, but I want to show this to the user using javascript).

Comment: could you add your mysql config code here ?

Comment: It looks like it might be just the `toString`'d variant of the error. Have you tried calling `err.toString()`?

Comment: Thats what i was looking. toString is the perfect solution. Thank you so much :D